compare two fonts and create a similarity score
I have a font library (let's say 100), I want to compare an external font eg: Arial to my font library and pick the font which is most similar to the Arial font.
I am new to this field, and while i was researching i found many confusing terms like glyph, Contours.. all are used interchangeably sometimes which is even more confusing
I tried creating an image with some text (using the fonts that i want to compare) and then calculating the Mean square error but it didn't work
I also tried googles library googlefonts/diffenator2 but that is made for comparing the different versions of the same font, and it creates a report of the things that changed between the versions, I want some script which can create a similarity score between two fonts.
I am not sure how I can achieve this, I am open to use any language, library or scripts.
I tried few things using the fonttools in python but i am not getting the desired results
